# Modal se abre siempre que haga click aunque tenga el eventListener en una imagen

Tags: javascript, modal, materialize

Es una cosa simple que me está llevando muchisimo tiempo.

Quiero abrir un modal al hacer click en cualquier imagen de productos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el HTML de la pagina:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="icon" th:href="@{/favicon_heladeria.png}" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/vendor/materialize/css/materialize.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/app.css}" />

    <title>Copito de Nieve | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <a th:href="@{/}" class="brand-logo">Heladeria</a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" class="button-collapse right"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li class="active"><a th:href="@{/}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/gustos}">Gustos</a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/ingresar}">Ingresar</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="mobile-nav" class="side-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a th:href="@{/}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/gustos}">Gustos</a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/ingresar}">Ingresar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="search-bar container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <form action="#" method="get">
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input name="q" type="search" placeholder="Buscar todos los helados..." required="required" autocomplete="off"/>
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class="mid-title">Productos</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="helados container">
        <div class="row">
            <div th:each="producto : ${productos}" class="col s12 l4">
                <img id="prod-img" th:src="@{'/images/' + ${producto.nombre} +'.png'}" />
                <p class="product-name" th:text="${producto.nombre}"></p>
                <p class="desc" th:text="${producto.descripcion}"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="prodModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Haga su pedido</h4>
                <p class="flavour" th:each="gusto : ${gustos}" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script th:src="@{/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/vendor/materialize/js/materialize.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/home.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Al hacer click el modal se abre con todos los gustos de helado de la base de datos tal como se espera, el problema es que se abre siempre que se haga click en cualquier lugar de la pagina y no cuando se clickea en las imagenes que es como debería abrirse.

Este es mi JS:

```
 var prodImages = document.querySelectorAll('#prod-img');
console.log(prodImages);
prodImages.forEach(elm => {
      addEventListener('click', () => {
      var element = document.querySelector('#prodModal');
      var modal = M.Modal.init(element, {});
      modal.open();
    }, false);
});
```

Estoy usando la libreria materialize y creo que el materialize.js es el que está haciendo el lio.

Comment: por que no agregas directamente el evento en la etiqueta de las imagenes asignándoles una función? Puedes agregar `onclick="openModal()"` . Tal vez logres solucionarlo de este modo. Dentro de `openModal()` realizas las acciones correspondientes. Deberías considerar editar el código y asignar **prod-img** como una clase. Los ID deben ser únicos para cada elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui no deberias ocupar IDs, si no clases

```
 var prodImages = document.querySelectorAll('#prod-img');
```

En fin siguiendo con tu codigo, al no poner el listener en el element, por default toma el window o document, asi que era eso:

```
prodImages.forEach(elm => {
      //agregar elm como el listener
      elm.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      //recuerda detener la propagación si es necesario
      event.stopPropagation();
      var element = document.querySelector('#prodModal');
      var modal = M.Modal.init(element, {});
      modal.open();
    }, false);
});
```

**Update: event.stopPropagation;**

El detener la propagación, aplica cuando hay objetos anidados. Supongamos que tenemos un `<div><img /></div>`

Y ambos `div` e `img` tienen eventos `click` sin embargo si se hace click dentro `img`, esto provoca que se haga un click en `div` y puede no ser lo que se quiere.

`stopPropagation()` ayuda a prevenir eso, y a respetar solo el click en el área designada.

Aquí intervienen otras cosas como la posición, z-index, visibilidad, etc.

Comment: **Sugerencia:** Reemplazar `querySelector` por `getElementById` ya que el mismo aun tiene problema de compatibilidad con algunos navegadores. En este caso seria innecesario correr ese riesgo.

Comment: explica esta linea `event.stopPropagation();` adicional

Comment: Oie @FranIslas  pero en ese caso trae solo el primero o se trae todos? :o por que no se si seria pasar a class y con `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: @elporfirio vaamos tu puedes, coloca enlace de referencia de firefox

Comment: En el caso de usar  `getElementById()` te trae solo uno, que sería lo mas lógico ya que los ID como te dije deben ser únicos. Pero si lo asignas como clase puedes usar `getElementsByClassName()` y vas a seleccionar todos los elementos que tengan dicha clase. Saludos!